# How to fix a particular column width in a same table

Tags: html, css, tablecolumn

```
<table class="striped">
    <tr><td width="25%">ASD</td></tr>
    <tr><td width="50%">ASD</td></tr>
</table>
```

By adding a border, it clearly shows that both row will be having the same exact width, which will be 50%. What is the simplest way to customize the second row width fix?

Comment: Try to add another table inside <tr> with no padding / margin for outer table

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an empty colunm for the first row. check this out:

```
<table class="striped">
    <tr><td>ASD</td><td class="abc"></td><</tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2">ASDsdfsdfsdf</td></tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table.striped td{
    border:1px solid #000;
    width:25%;
}
.abc {
    border:0 !important;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/xr5cd8o5/)